# jruby 1.6.1 on rails 3.0.7 with mysql 2 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

i create new project with jruby 1.6.1 and rails 3.0.7

i do required change for jruby

create scaffold and when i goto rake db:migrate it give me this error

The driver encountered an unknown error: java.sql.SQLException:
java.lang.ClassFormatError: com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM is saying that the driver class file is not valid. 
The classes in the mysql driver might be corrupt (unlikely) or maybe the version of java you are running is too old to read the class file.

I suggest you upgrade Java to the latest version and download the Mysql drivers again.